# Sinatra + HTTPS redirect to HTTP?

Tags: ruby, ssl, https, sinatra, ssl-certificate

Is it possible to have a Sinatra web server detect an HTTPS:// connection and redirect it to a HTTP:// connection with the same URL, and not have to deal with SSL certificates? I tried stunnel to redirect but it's asking for a cert.

Answer (score 2):

With HTTPS, the first thing a browser does is to create a secure connection to the webserver. For this, it requires a valid server certificate. Before the secure connection is established, you can not perform any HTTP redirect yet.

Thus, to be able to perform any redirects from https to http, you need to have a valid SSL certificate on the server. And in that case, you should really think about having SSL enabled for all content anyway.

Comment: This is entirely correct and I second the advice about enabling SSL by default, but FYI to anyone viewing this and wanting to detect a secure connection within a Sinatra app, there is [`request.secure?`](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Accessing%20the%20Request%20Object)